# Can pandoc generate a bibliography with the references in order of citation?

Tags: pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

Pandoc noob here.  I am trying to convert a LaTeX file into a Word document for submission to a picky journal.  They are requiring that my references appear in the bibliography in the order in which they are cited.  This is no problem in LaTeX, but when I use Pandoc to convert to Word my references appear in alphabetical order.  I am using the basic command:

```
pandoc my.tex --bibliography=my.bib -o my.docx
```

Is there any way to force Pandoc to print the references in the order in which they appear in-text?  Ideally, the references would appear in-text as numbers (bracketed, superscripted, I don't care) and the list of references would be numbered accordingly.

Any help in the direction of reducing the amount of manual work I will have to do is much appreciated.

Comment: This can be controlled by using a style defined in [citation style language](https://citationstyles.org/). Best to ask the journal if they have one, or if they can tell you a style close to the one they use.